# How would I receive all fields from a dynamic form with Struts?

Tags: forms, dynamic, struts-1

I found myself with the following problem:

I have a page generated with `logic:iterate` that shows the current supervisor and assistant of a service. 
That page also acts as a form where people can add their possible substitutes, but you never know how many of those are there.

Due to the environment I am currently working with it had to be without JSTL so a lot of options were gone; couldn't get `DynaActionForm` working for this either.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find anything but I already got the answer I decided to create this to answer anyone who might have the same issue.

Code:

```
public ActionForward post(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String[] tot;

    try {       
        Enumeration<?> fieldsForm = request.getParameterNames();

        while(fieldsForm.hasMoreElements()) {
            String current = (String) fieldsForm.nextElement();
            tot = request.getParameterValues(current);

            System.out.println("Field name is: " + current);
            for (i=0; i<tot.length; i++) {
                // do whatever you need to do; contents are in tot[i]
                System.out.println("Value " + i + " is: " + tot[i]);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```